# Best way to distribute and exchange a commonly shared NSManagedObjectContext across the entire app?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

For the purpose of creating persistent store backups, I have to use the framework's `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` method as a "SaveAs..." operation. After that, the old persistent store is removed from the coordinator (what I don't want). To get back the old store on the coordinator, I use remove the backup store with `removePersistentStore:error:` and add the old one back with `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`. At that point, all `NSManagedObject`s must not be used anymore, because Core Data considers them as having been loaded from another store (despite I've re-added the it after the migration).

The problem: My AppDelegate passed its MOC to the first view controller which then passed it along to the next view controller and so on. I have a fairly complex app in terms of UI and background services. What's the best way to pass the MOC along in the app and exchange it once it's necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dependency injection then I would create the set accessor so that when it is called it passes the context down as needed as well as flags anything for a rebuild as needed.

However, this question becomes moot based on the answer I posted on your other question.